# FullCalendar: specify extra callback in secondary JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am initializing my default FullCalendar settings in `file1.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function() {
      someFunction();
    },
    etc..
  })
});
```

And now I'd like to add a specific `callback` like `eventAfterAllRender` in `file2.js` for customization purposes (let's say a user-specific action upon `eventAfterAllRender` which differs per user).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: function() {
      console.log('eventAfterAllRender');
    }
  })
});
```

Is there a way to do this without having to merge both files into a single file?
If I keep it in two files and include it in a page it initializes twice in de same div.

Comment: If you keep it in 2 files and include both in same html ..what is breaking?

Comment: @Neha it initializes twice in de same div. Have updated question

Comment: second call would simply initialize plugin again. Explain higher level `customization purposes` further

Comment: @charlietfl Gave explaining it a try

Comment: Its late but this seems to be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063568/insert-event-dynamically-to-fullcalendar-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to do it, but you can do something like below using a custom event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function () {
            someFunction();
        },
        eventAfterAllRender: function (e) {
            $('#calendar').trigger('fullcalendarallrender', e)
        }
    })
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').on('fullcalendarallrender', function (e, view) {});
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g36Ts/)

Comment: That seems to work @Arun! Will mark this as the answer for now